# SQL Server Table locks in long query - Solution: NoLock?

Tags: sql, sql-server

a report in my application runs a query that needs between 5 - 15 seconds (constrained to count of rows that will be returned).
The query has 8 joins to nearly all main-tables of my application (Customers, sales, units etc).

A little tool shows me, that in this time, all those 8 tables are locked with a shared table lock. That means, no update operation will be done in this time.

A solution from a friend is, to have every join in the query, which is not mandetory to have 100% correct data (dirty read), with a NoLock, so only 1 of this 8 tables will be locked completly.
Is that a good solution? For a report in which 99% of data came from one table, unlock the less prio tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT rather than NOLOCK. This means the data could be "old" but will never be dirty.

Answer (score 4):

`NOLOCK` means placing no locks at all.

Your query may returns portions of data as of before `UPDATE` and portions as of after `UPDATE` *in a single query*.

Like, a debit without a credit and these kinds of stuff.

For instance, I just ran this query on a large table:

```
SELECT  SUM(LEN(name))
FROM    master WITH (NOLOCK)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

---
18874367
```

All `name`'s have length of `1`.

Then I reran it and in the middle of the query updated the table:

```
UPDATE  master
SET     name = 'tt'
WHERE   id <= 10000

SELECT  SUM(LEN(name))
FROM    master WITH (NOLOCK)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

---
18874944
```

As we can see, this query noticed `577` rows as updated (length `2`), all other rows as not updated (length `1`).

```
SELECT  SUM(LEN(name))
FROM    master WITH (NOLOCK)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

---
18884367
```

And this query, run right after the previous one finished, sees all updates.

Comment: Understand I it right? You mean when in the 15 seconds where the select query run, there will be a fast update for e.g. the customeraddress, then the half will be have the first address and the other half the new one?

Comment: "NOLOCK means placing no locks at all." This is not correct. NOLOCK = igNOre LOCK (not official). Ignoring locks by using NOLOCK IS how you get uncommitted data. Aaron Bertrand points out that NOLOCK hint queries will take out locks in this article: sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere See the section about bad name choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, as long as you place a very strong emphasis on this phrase:

> which is not mandetory to have 100% correct data (dirty read)

So you probably don't want to add a nolock hint to your sales table, but your customers table (which likely sees fewer changes) might be okay. Even there, you're probably not using that many customer records in a single query, but if one does change it could be a big problem.  So you might want to specify the `rowlock` hint for that table.