# Large Table handling

Tags: sql-server, bigdata

We are having table that contains `6,616,711` records in it. I want to know, How to manage this table? If there is SO question similar to this please give me link. Having following concern, too.

- How to manage large database?
- What is best system/hardware configuration for this type of scenario?
- Partitioning this table will help us?

Comment: 6.6 million or 66 million?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited at [dba.se].

Comment: What do you mean by 'manage' ?

Comment: @Luftwaffe that server will respond faster steps should be taken care while dealing with large database

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930696/querying-large-table-in-sql-server-2008